Cases of $\lvert x^2-a\rvert<b$
I am studying Introduction to Calculus and Analysis 1 by Richard Courant, SECTION 1.1e, page 12, Question 1. (c).
The question: "Using signs of inequality alone (not using signs of absolute value) specify the values of $x$ which satisfy $\lvert x^2-a\rvert<b$."
I have worked out a solution, but it does not seem to encapsulate all cases. I want to know how I should have done the algebra differently, so that I could have arrived upon those cases just through algebraic manipulation.
My Work
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lvert x^2-a\rvert<b&\iff(-b<x^2-a)\land(x^2-a<b)\\
&\iff(a-b<x^2)\land(x^2<b+a)\\
&\iff(x<-\sqrt{a-b}\lor x>\sqrt{a-b})\land(-\sqrt{a+b}<x\land x<\sqrt{b+a})
\end{aligned}
$$
This seems to say that if $\neg(-\sqrt{a+b}<x\land x<\sqrt{b+a})$, then $x\in\emptyset$ (which is true). If $(-\sqrt{a+b}<x\land x<\sqrt{b+a})$, then $x$ is either greater than $-\sqrt{a-b}$, or less than $\sqrt{a-b}$. I don't think the second part is true. I also don't think that all cases are exhausted.
Based on my suspicion that my results were incorrect, I constructed a graphic. It seems to indicate the following:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x\in\emptyset&\quad\mbox{if}\quad-a>b\\
x\in(-\sqrt{a+b},\sqrt{a+b})&\quad\mbox{if}\quad(-a<b\land a<b)\\
x\in((-\sqrt{a+b},-\sqrt{a-b})\cup(\sqrt{a-b},\sqrt{a+b})&\quad\mbox{if}\quad a\geq b
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
How could I have gotten to these separate intervals, just from algebraic manipulation alone?


Final answer should be $~a-b < x^2 < a+b~$ and $~a \leq x^2.~$ Note that if $~b < 0~$ or $~(a + b) \leq 0,~$ then there are no solutions.

@user2661923 Thank you, that will help me validate my attempts

@user2661923 I will try and work backwards from $(a-b<x^2\land x^2<a+b)\land(a\leq x^2)\land(\neg(b<0)\land\neg(a+b\leq 0))$

@user2661923 Sorry to ping you again, but does that imply that my step in $\lvert x^2-a\rvert<b\iff(-b<x^2-a)$ was wrong? My solution seems to agree with you about the $a-b<x^2<a+b\land a\leq x^2$ part, but doesn't include the restrictions. In the future, how could I be aware of those restrictions when they occur?

Sorry, that's meant to say (1) $\lvert x^2-a\rvert<b\iff(-b<x^2-a)\land(x^2-a<b)$ and (2) $a-b<x^2<a+b$

Actually, my first comment was wrong.  There is no $~a \leq x^2~$ constraint; that was my mistake.  Beyond that, you have that $~0 \leq |x^2 - a| < b \implies 0 < b.~$  So, there is no solution if $~b \leq 0 ~$ (again, 2nd minor mistake in my first comment). Also, you have that $~0 \leq x^2 < a + b \implies 0 < a + b.~$  Therefore, there is no solution if $~a + b \leq 0.$

Jasper, does Courant assume (at least) $b>0$ in this question?

@AnneBauval $b>0$ was not an assumption.

Let $c:=a-b$ and $d:=a+b$.

$c<x^2$ is not equivalent to
$$(x<-\sqrt c)\lor(x>\sqrt c),$$ which we'll denote by $P$, but to
$$(c<0)\lor(c\ge0\land P).$$
$x^2<d$ is not equivalent to
$$-\sqrt d<x<\sqrt d,$$
which we'll denote by $Q$, but to
$$(d\ge0)\land Q.$$
Therefore, $c<x^2<d$ is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}\text{false}&\text{if }d<0\\
Q&\text{if }d\ge0>c\\
Q\land P&\text{if }d,c\ge0.
\end{cases}$$

Edit. $x^2<d$ is also equivalent to $(d\color{red}>0)\land Q$, hence $c<x^2<d$ is also equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}\text{false}&\text{if }d\le0\\
Q&\text{if }d>0>c\\
Q\land P&\text{if }d>0\land c\ge0,
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}\text{false}&\text{if }a+b\le0\\
-\sqrt{a+b}<x<\sqrt{a+b}&\text{if }a+b>0\land a<b\\
-\sqrt{a+b}<x<-\sqrt{a-b}\lor\sqrt{a-b}<x<\sqrt{a+b}&\text{if }a+b>0\land a\ge b.
\end{cases}$$

I didn't consider that those implicit inequalities ($c\geq0,\ d\geq0$) should be part of the Boolean statement itself. Writing it precisely like this makes it much more clear.
